# Alignment of multi-dimensional array for omp simd

Tags: fortran, openmp, simd

If I understand the `aligned` clause of the `omp simd` construct, it refers to the alignment of the whole array.

How is it used for multi-dimensional arrays? Assume

```
ni = 131; nj = 137; nk = 127

!allocates  arr(1:131,1:137,1:127) aligned to 64-bytes
call somehow_allocate_aligned(arr, [ni,nj,nk], 64)

!$omp parallel do collapse(2)
do k = 1, nk
  do j = 1, nj

    call some_complicated_subroutine(arr(:,j,k))

    !$omp simd aligned(arr:64)
    do i = 1, ni
      arr(i,j,k) = some arithmetic expression involving arr(i,j,k)
    end do
  end do
end do
!$omp end parallel do
```

Is this the correct way to indicate the alignment of the array although the iteration of the inner loop starts at `arr(1,j,k)`?

How does the compiler use that information to infer anything about the alignment of the inner loop subarray?

Does it matter for the performance if the run-time sizes are nicer (say 128, 128, 128)?

Comment: Because you're only performing SIMD vectorization along the `i` axis, you only have to align your `arr` array to 64-bytes in that dimension. The other dimensions can be arbitrary lengths and it should not effect your vectorization at all. You can always double check whether the alignment you set up and the vectorization that is performed are consistent by looking at the output compiling with `-qopenmp-simd -qopt-report=5`.

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll Fortran arrays don't work like that (aligning along one dimension). They are contiguous. Which compiler supports the options you referenced?

Comment: Yes, Fortran arrays are contiguous. But the `simd` construct in your case is only working along 1 axis, so to that construct you are basically handing it a 1D slice of your array. That slice is the only piece that has to be aligned. (Also, aligning the fastest dimension to 64-bytes automatically implies the 3D array will be aligned to 64-bytes anyway...) And yes those were ifort options.

Comment: My point was, that `arr(:,2,1)` is (can be) aligned differently than `arr`. It can be avoided by allocating a larger array in FORTRAN77 style, but that will incure a big number of challenges for other parts of the code.

Comment: And even if the array happens to be of such a size that the contiguous pieces (columns?) are aligned the same way, will the compiler be able to know that? How do I tell it such information?

Comment: Sorry but I don't see what you're talking about. If the fastest dimension of `arr` is aligned to a given size, then your total array `arr` will also be aligned by definition to that same size. If `ni` is divisible by 64, then by definition `nj*nk*ni` is also divisible by 64 for any integers `nk` and `ni`.

Comment: As to your second question, I thought that was the very purpose of the `aligned(arr:64)` clause. You are telling the compiler that the pieces of the array you are working on are aligned to 64 bytes.

Comment: But according to the OpenMP specification the clause is about the pointer to the array, there is no reference to first dimension pieces I could find.

Comment: You are telling the compiler that the `arr(1,1,1)` is aligned to 64 bytes. `arr(1,2,1)` is obviously not since `131` is a prime number. The compiler will most likely generate vectorised code with additional scalar code to handle the non-aligned parts.

Comment: That is what I supposed. The problem is that the compiler probably cannot generally find out whether all `arr(:,i,j)` are aligned or not at compile time. I can only imagine very dirty tricks. I can't find any way how to tell the compiler they are aligned even if I did the additional work and made them to be so (assuming a typical assumed shape or explicit (non-constant) size dummy argument).

Comment: The target of `aligned` is either an allocatable array or a pointer. Align your columns by rounding `ni` appropriately and then instead of `arr(:,j,k)` use a 1D pointer associated with `arr(1:ni,j,k)` and tell the compiler about the alignment of the pointer target. The compiler might actually be able to figure out the array dimensions at compile time via constant propagation. Otherwise it will perform the checks in runtime when the dimensions are known for sure.

Answer (score 1):

It is explained here, slides 160-165 : http://irpf90.ups-tlse.fr/files/parallel_programming.pdf

You should

1) Align the array

2) use padding to force all your columns to be aligned : Your first dimension (specified in the allocate statement) should be a multiple of the number of elements to reach the 16, 32 or 64 -byte boundary depending on the instruction set.

For example, for a 99x29x200 matrix with the AVX instruction set (32 bytes alignment) in double precision (8 bytes/element), you should do

```
n = 99
l = 29
m=200

delta_n = mod(n,32/8)
if (delta_n == 0) then
  n_pad = n
else
  n_pad = n-delta_n+32/8
end if

allocate( A(n_pad,l,m) )
!DIR$ ATTRIBUTES ALIGN : 32 :: A

do k=1,m
  do j=1,l
    !$OMP SIMD
    do i=1,n
      A(i,j,k) = ...
    end do
  end do
end do
```

You can use the C preprocessor to make portable code replacing the 32 and 8 in the previous example.

Note : be careful using statements such as B=A for arrays, as the physical dimensions will not correspond to the logical dimensions. Good practice is to set the boundaries as B(1:n,1:l,1:m) = A(1:n,1:l,1:m) as it will still work if you change the physical dimensions.

Comment: The reference does not appear to consider the OpenMP simd construct. The ATTRIBUTES ALIGN directive is similar, but I don't know if it is guaranteed to have the same semantics. Also, not all of my compilers know this directive. The question is also, even if I make the effort and align the columns (that causes problems elsewhere), will the compiler know and use the knowledge, that the columns are aligned? How do I tell it to the compiler?

Comment: The ``!DIR$`` directives are Intel specific. They seem to be more mature than the ``!$OMP SIMD`` for vectorization : https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler-for-linux-and-mac-os-x/topic/509157 
You can tell the compiler that an array is already aligned using ``!$OMP SIMD aligned(A)``. The compiler will take advantage of alignment, but if the array is not aligned, you may get a segmentation fault. However,  I couldn't find how to tell gfortran to align arrays....

Comment: I can always create a pointer array from a call to `memalign`, that is not a big problem.

Comment: That's true, so in that case it should work. You can try to write a small test containing a vectorized loop, compile it with the ``-g`` option and check that the loop was vectorized in the generated assembly code (``objdump -d test.o``).

Comment: Or simply compile with `-S` and enjoy the annotated assembly output.